# How to get the certain element in a Set on a .forEach iteration in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, foreach, iterator, set

What is the expression after the "pairedDevices" in order to get this certain element that satisfies the if condition?

```
//creating a SET of paired devices
    val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices

    //for each paired device
    pairedDevices?.forEach { device ->
        if (device.name == "HC-05") {
            val hc05 = pairedDevices

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

`hc05 = pairedDevices?.first { it.name == "HC-05" }`

Comment: .first means "the first one (by index)" or "the first one that satisfies the name condition"?